# Occasional client credentials rejection when running WCF through VPN

Tags: wcf, credentials, nettcpbinding

Recently I migrated my company's product client-server communication from socket based Kerberos enabled tcp/ip communication within corporate intranet to WCF with netTcpBinding, Windows security and encryption and signing on, impersonation turned off. After quite a lot reading everything was ready and operational within our test environment, so we exposed service contract in production release. Clients from within intranet communicate smoothly with server, but the once who are connected through VPN suffer from occasional "The server has rejected client credentials" exception. Log off/log in fixes things by their side, but just for a couple of minutes. Windows user's password, I tested with is a fresh one.
I tried to disabling connection pooling, but this didn't fix the problem. Any ideas what might be wrong with our infrastructure or WCF configuration ?